# setTitle:forState: doesn't work in dispatch_after()

Tags: ios, uibutton, grand-central-dispatch

All:

I am trying to 
i) disable a button with a title of Count
ii)  change its title to Busy, and after a delay of delta seconds 
iii) enable the button and 
iv)  change its title back to Count

This all is supposed to happen in the code for the UIButton's action.

I can do steps i)-iii), but step iv) does not work:

```
[sender setEnabled:NO];  // the button is now disabled, clicking on it has no effect 
[sender setTitle:@"Busy ... " forState:UIControlStateDisabled];


// wait delay seconds before reenabling the count button
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delta * NSEC_PER_SEC),
               dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
               [self.countBTN setEnabled:YES];
               [self.countBTN setTitle:@"Count" forState:UIControlStateReserved];
               });

// after delta seconds, the button is re-enabled, but its title is still "Busy ..."
```

Any insights into why this isn't working would be *greatly* appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run the UI code on the main thread, not a background thread.

Change:

```
dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
```

to:

```
dispatch_get_main_queue()
```

Edit:

You might also need to change `UIControlStateReserved` to `UIControlStateNormal` if you want to change the main title of the button.